# What exactly is this Rails error (wrong number of arguments) telling me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

When running some test with RSpec, I get this error (multiple times):

```
1) User Pages edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: visit edit_user_path(user)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./app/views/users/edit.html.haml:15:in `block in _app_views_users_edit_html_haml__2466546393595631499_70225077026800'
     # ./app/views/users/edit.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_haml__2466546393595631499_70225077026800'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not familiar with reading Rails error messages; is this telling me the method being called with the wrong number of arguments is in edit.html.haml, or in user_pages_spec.rb? Is it saying that edit_user_path is being called with 0 arguments?

Edit to add my code:

edit.html.haml:

```
- provide(:title, "Edit user")
%h1 Update your profile

.row
    .span6.offset3
        = form_for(@user) do |f|

            = f.label :name
            = f.text_field :name

            = f.label :email
            = f.text_field :email

            = f.label :password
            = f.password_field

            = f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password"
            = f.password_field :password_confirmation

            = f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

Relevant portion of user_pages_spec.rb:

```
describe "edit" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            sign_in user
            visit edit_user_path(user)
        end

        describe "page" do
            it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
            it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
        end

        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Save changes" }

            it { should have_content('error') }
        end

        describe "with valid information" do
            let(:new_name) { "New Name" }
            let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
            before do
                fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
                fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
                fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
                fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
                click_button "Save changes"
            end

            it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
            it { should have_success_message('') }
            it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
            specify { user.reload.name.should == new_name }
            specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
        end 
    end
```

Comment: It would be help to answer better, if you post your spec and the edit.haml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, wrong number of arguments means that for the method, it thinks that you should be passing a certain number of variables in, and it's receiving the wrong amount.

In this case, it expects 1 variable to be passed in and it's receiving none.

From the looks of it, you should be looking at line 15 of your edit.html.haml file, which I'm guessing is here:

```
= f.label :password
= f.password_field
```

It looks like you're missing :password -- passing the actual variable in.

So change it to:

```
= f.password_field :password
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that generally, the top line referenced in the error block (e.g. `# ./app/views/users/edit.html.haml:15:in `block in _app_views_users_edit_html_haml__2466546393595631499_70225077026800'`) points to the problem?

Comment: Yes. What you're looking at is called a stack trace, or a brack trace. It's showing you the order that methods were called. So ruby was running the users_pages_spec and on line 54 it encountered code that made it go to the edit page. On the edit page on line 6 it encountered code that made it go to another part in the edit page. Then on line 15 in the edit page it encountered the error.

Comment: There are times when you will have to go farther down the trace though. Generally it's the first line. But what I do is start at the top (which is the end) of the trace and backtrack until I find the first file that I know / I created and look at that line.

Answer (score 2):

So the top of the stack trace is the last method called, and it progresses down the chain from there. This is indicating the error is in the edit file. If you pasted the whole edit file, it looks like like 15 is missing an argument to the password field. Should be:

```
= f.password_field :password
```